# Flutter url_launcher blocked popup

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I want to redirect user from flutter web app to another url.

I use url_launcher with the following code:

```
if(await canLaunch(link)){
            await launch(link);
          }else{
            print('faild to load url');
          }
```

this code is working fine in other pages of my application. but not working in one of the pages and i get `popup window blocked` in my browser.

the code is working fine on chrome(desktop and mobile). but the problem occurs on safari.

update: in the page where the problem is occuring I have a http request and then launch the url.

```
var url = Uri.parse(Api.completeOrder);
      var response = await http.post(url, body: {
        'token': token,
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          if(await canLaunch(link)){
            await launch(link);
          }else{
            print('faild to load url');
          }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything different about the link compared to other pages?

Comment: @developerextraordinare i tested the other pages and even googles url but i still have the problem

Comment: I'm not sure there's not enough information in your question to figure out the problem. What is different about the page that doesn't work vs the other pages in your application?